# Are questions about how to further golf a program on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Based on the [FAQ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), I know I should limit my questions to specific challenges that have an "objective winning criterion." This leads me to assume that questions like those I'm asking about are not.

However, the simple algorithm I'm attempting to golf (a weasel program) depends on several pseudo-random steps, it's (pseudo)-non-deterministic. Simply posing it as a challenge seems like a problem because although I could specify the seed I used when I coded it in the original language (Python), I imagine that will still cause the results to differ between languages that use different pseudo-random algorithms.

If I just pose the question as "how can I further golf this program?" and provide my **working** code in its current state, is that acceptable, or is this more on-topic for Stack Overflow? I assumed that if I posted a question related to code-golf there, it would be migrated over here anyway, but the FAQ here leaves me uncertain. I have read the [Python tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/7849) question as well.

Perhaps it's not on topic on any SE site, which is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take has been that "How do I golf *this* program?" type questions are too localized.

We do, however, have a series of [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions where you can find (on a per-language basis) suggested techniques for golfing or abusing language features; In my mind that is different because the answers should apply again and again.

Comment: Right, I read the Python tips question and applied several of those tips to my code. I may just post the algorithm as a simple challenge anyway and see what responses people give, despite the fact that it relies on pseudo-random components.

Comment: So, what are we supposed to do when the existing tips aren't enough? For example, is [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15425/doing-shorter-comparisons-in-powershell) question - not about a specific piece of code, but centered around how to better golf a particular operation in general - still okay?

Answer (score 3):

From the FAQ of the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), I *think* it would be on topic there: you post code and want feedback on a specific point. However, I'd ask first in meta there because I'm not sure whether they would consider that a deficiency in the FAQ.

Comment: Based on the [answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/711/24269), it doesn't look like it's a good fit there either.